# Proving a problem about derivatives

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $f'$ exists in a neighborhood of $x=a$ and $\underset{x\to a^+}{\text{lim}}f'(x)=L$. Prove that $f'(a)=L$.

Attempt:

Since $f$ is differentiable in a ngbhd of a, then there is some $\xi$ in the neighborhood of $a$, say $(a,x)$ so that $f'( \xi ) = \dfrac{ f(x) - f(a) }{x-a } $

Since $\lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x) = L $ holds for any $x$, then with $x = \xi$, we obtain

$$ \lim_{x \to a^+} \dfrac{ f(x)- f(a) }{x-a} = f'(a) $$

Thus $L = f'(a)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Unclear what you mean in the first paragraph. Presumably you want to take $x$ in the nbhd of $a$ then use mean value theorem. Note then that $\xi$ depends on $x$, but is sandwiched between $x$ and $a$. All in all, I'd say your proof isn't correct as written, but, could easily be improved to be.